# Tkinter MultiLevel Inheritance for Frames

Tags: python, tkinter, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm having trouble getting widgets to show on a frame that uses multi-level inheritance. I have these 2 classes:

```
class ScrollableFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, name, width=0, height=0, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs, width=width, height=height)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack_propagate(False)

        self.label = Label(self, text=name)
        self.label.pack()
        self.sp = Separator(self)
        self.sp.pack(fill="x")

        self.v = Scrollbar(self)
        self.v.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.c = Canvas(self, width=width, height=height, yscrollcommand=self.v.set)
        self.interior = Frame(self.c)
        self.interior.bind("<Configure>", self.reset_scrollregion)
        self.interior.pack()

        self.c.create_window((0, 0), window=self.interior, anchor="nw")
        self.c.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.c.configure(scrollregion=self.c.bbox("all")))

        self.c.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        self.v.config(command=self.c.yview)

    def reset_scrollregion(self, event):
        self.c.configure(scrollregion=self.c.bbox("all"))


class GroupFrame(ScrollableFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):

        ScrollableFrame.__init__(self, parent, "Groups", *args, **kwargs, width=200, height=600)

        self.group_list = []

        # Populate Header
        self.input = Entry(self, width=150)
        self.input.pack()
        self.input.insert(0, "Enter Group Name...")

        self.submit_btn = Button(self, width=150, text="Submit", command=self.group_entry)
        self.submit_btn.pack()
        self.sp_header = Separator(self)
        self.sp_header.pack(fill=X, pady=5)

    def group_entry(self):
        group = Group(self.interior, self.input.get())
        self.group_list.append(group)
```

When I make a GroupFrame object and display it, I only get this: [image]

No widgets that I added in the GroupFrame class show up. I think it's because in the GroupFrame class, 'self' doesn't count as a Frame since it inherits and initializes from ScrollableFrame. Is there any way to fix this or do I have to scrap the GroupFrame class and code it procedural instead?

Comment: Any content that you want to be scrollable has to be added to the `interior` attribute, not the `ScrollableFrame` (or child class) itself.  I believe that your incorrectly added widgets are not showing up because the fixed-height Canvas is pushing them off the bottom of the outer Frame.

Comment: You're right! It was pushing out the bottom I can't believe I missed that! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

As @jasonharper mentioned above, I missed the fact that the interior frame that was meant to be scrollable pushed the rest of the widgets out the bottom of the frame. All I had to do is put the widgets above the interior in another frame called header and in the GroupFrame class I could choose to put input and button in the header frame.